# How to redirect a page through JavaScript if a variable need is met

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, variables

I have a block of codes from different websites in my files and me and my friends want to make a game. The idea is if the variable chosenPath is not selected yet then redirect to pathChooser.html to select this value to make the chosenPath select so that the variable is defined so the redirection would cancel.

pathChooser.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoo Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pathText">
    <form id="pathChoiceForm">
        <select id="pathSelect" placeholder="Choose Your Path">
            <option value="Hunter">Hunter</option>
            <option value="Zoo Keeper">Zoo Keeper</option>
            <option value="Animal Enthusiast">Animal Enthusiast</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="pathChosen" id="pathChosen" value="Select" action="index.html">
    </form>
    </div>
    
    <style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var path = document.getElementById('pathText');
var chosenPath = document.getElementById('pathSelect').value;
var redirector = document.getElementById('redirector');


function choosePath() {
    path.innerHTML = chosenPath;
}

if (chosenPath = undefined) {
    window.location.href = "pathChooser";
    choosePath();
}
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoo Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="redirector" href="pathChooser"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I need to add some PHP because I am very bad at that!

Comment: Here is what happens given your scenario: `load index.html --> path is not chosen so redirect to pathChooser.html (and lose everything from index.html) --> choose path and redirect to index.html (and lose everything from pathChooser.html) --> path is not chosen so redirect to ....` and on and on. It might be better (and a better user experience) to simply hide/show the part of the page that is needed. Show only pathChooser part if path is needed and show only main part if path has been provided.

Comment: A quick look: shouldn't it be `if(chosenPath == undefined)` instead of with `=`?  And also `window.location.href="pathChooser"`?  I think you meant `pathChooser.html` or something similar.

Comment: *Face Palms* Yeah, I rushed it thanks for that. I noticed it when I was touching up the code and wasn't bothered to change my question.